# Python : Appending Integer array in list while iterating

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I have an integer array say offset=array('i',[0,0])

```
off=[]
offset=array('i',[0,0])
for each in [1,2,3]:
    offset[0]=j+each
    offset[1]=k+each
    print(offset)
    off.append(offset)
print(off)
```

I am appending the array in a list say off. 
My expected output is :

```
array('i', [2, 11])
array('i', [3, 12])
array('i', [4, 13])
[array('i', [2, 11]), array('i', [2, 12]), array('i', [4, 13])]
```

But, i am getting the output as:

```
array('i', [2, 11])
array('i', [3, 12])
array('i', [4, 13])
[array('i', [4, 13]), array('i', [4, 13]), array('i', [4, 13])]
```

Can anybody please help me in sorting it out ?

Comment: Read through this post about [shallow copy vs deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) of lists. The reason I bring this up is because you are storing a copy of the same list in all your arrays, which is causing the problem you see.

Answer (score 1):

I think *j = 1*, and *k = 10*

and use your code like this:

```
from array import array

j,k = 1,10

off=[]
#offset=array('i',[0,0])
for each in [1,2,3]:
    offset=array('i',[0,0]) # move to here

    offset[0]=j+each
    offset[1]=k+each
    print(offset)
    off.append(offset)
print(off)
```

*copy* could help you, check [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) as **Cyber** advised you

```
from array import array
from copy import copy
j,k = 1,10

off=[]
offset_base=array('i',[0,0])
for each in [1,2,3]:
    offset=copy(offset_base)

    offset[0]=j+each
    offset[1]=k+each
    print(offset)
    off.append(offset)
print(off)
```